# How to add a class to all the input elements inside a form in cakephp

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

How do i use the `inputDefaults` to add a common class to all the input elements in my form. also pls give a brief description of the `inputDefaults`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

isn't it:

> ```
> echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
>   'inputDefaults' => array(
>     'class' => 'someclass'
>   )
> );
> ```
>
> `

Answer (score 0):

You should read the cookbook. theres a good example: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1639/options-inputDefaults

When you create a form you add inputdefaults key in options:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'div' => array('class' => 'someclass')
    )
);
```

Comment: i know tat. but how to add a common class to all `input` elements. see the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the source file i didn't find anything either. So the only way is to use it explicitly for every call to the `input` function.